# AGOL Dashboard - Select Attribute from List

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, select-by-attribute, operations-dashboard

I've compiled a database of proposals and geolocated them, while giving each entry / feature a "tag" of 1-3 values, separated by commas. In AGOL's Dashboard's Category Selector, I can only create a drop down menu for the entire string of the values. For example:

I have: "Bridge, Roads, Sings" as a single field. I want to be able to select "Bridge" and have all features that contain "Bridge" be selected. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

In short: no. The Category Selector only operates on an "equals" basis, not "contains". You might try working with Experience Builder, as many similar widgets there, such as the **List** widget, can have pre-configured filters that work with "contains"

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I managed to bypass with a filter command in a custom web app using "Contains", with multiple toggle switches. Thanks for the help